# Display html link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In some part of an html page, I have a link with the following code :

```
<a id="idname" class="classname" href="www.MySite.com/image-name.jpg">link-text</a>
```

I would like to **automatically display the same link in another part of the same page by using a javascript**.

What would be the script to insert in my page ?

Thank you in advance for any help in this matter.

Patrick

Comment: You can't copy the element identically, its `id` needs to be unique.  So you'll need to create another distinct element.

Comment: are you trying to insert the whole tag into different page?

Comment: In the question he said "automatically display the same link in another part of the same page by using a javascript."

Comment: @David He want to `move`the link element, not copy.

Comment: @reporter: Where does the question say that?  I read: `"display the same link in another part of the same page"`.  "Another" implies a second instance.

Comment: ok, that's another possible option :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myVar = document.getElementById("idname");
varLink = (myVar.attributes.href);
```

Comment: No, the OP want to move the link object to another place.

Comment: He can display the varLink content to a div in the page using document.getElementById("IDdivToContainTheLink").innerHTML = varLink;

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        // get data from link we want to copy
        var aHref = document.getElementById('idname').href;
        var aText = document.getElementById('idname').innerHTML;

        // create new link element with data above
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.innerHTML = aText;
        a.href = aHref;
        // paste our link to needed place
        var placeToCopy = document.getElementById('anotherplace');
        placeToCopy.appendChild(a);
    }
</script>
```

Use code above, if you want just to **copy** your link to another place. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bo46f6wt/)

Answer (score 0):

As son as you know the target id:

```
<div id="targetID">New Link: </div>
<div id="targetID2">New Link 2: </div>
```

And If you are using jQuery you can do like this:

```
var link = $("#idname").clone();
link.attr("id",link.attr("id") + (Math.random() * 10));
$("#targetID").append(link);
```

If not:

```
var link = document.getElementById("idname");
var newLink = document.createElement("a");
newLink.href = link.href;
newLink.className = link.className;
newLink.innerHTML = link.innerHTML;
newLink.id = link.id + (Math.random() * 10);
document.getElementById("targetID2").appendChild(newLink);
```

See this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/k4z29h0p/)

Comment: I think he want to use plain Javascript, not Jquery

Comment: That's why I've put both examples! I also want to show that he could write less code by using jQuery;

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that if you will just copy the element that will throw an error because the copied element will have the same id of the first one, so if you will create a copy of your element you don't have to give it the same id.

**Try this code:**

```
function copyLink(newDestination){
    var dest=document.getElementById(newDestination);
    var newLink=document.createElement("a");
    var myLink=document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[0];
    newLink.href=myLink.href;
    newLink.className = myLink.className;
    newLink.innerHTML = myLink.innerHTML;
    newDestination.appendChild(newLink);
}
```

The `newDestination` parameter is the container element of the new Link.

For example if the new Container element has the id "div1":

```
window.onload = function() {
    copyLink(div1);
}
```

**[Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k1pkqat7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to everyone for so many prompt replies.

**Finally, I was able to use Jquery**.
So, I tried the solution given by **Andrew Lancaster**.

In my page, I added the codes as follows, in this order :

1-

```
<span id="span1">
    <a class="classname" href="www.MySite.com/image-name.jpg">link-text</a>
</span>
<p>
    <span id="span2"></span>
</p>
```

and further down the page :

2-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var span1val = $('#span1').html();
    $('#span2').html(span1val);
</script>
```

Therefore, **the two expected identical links are properly displayed**.

But, unfortunately, I forgot to say something in my initial request:

- the original link is in the bottom part of my page
- I would like to have the duplicated link in a upper part of my page

**So, would you know how to have the duplicated link above the original link** ?

*By the way, to solve the invalid markup mentioned by David, I just deleted id="idname" from the original link (that I could ignored or replaced by other means).*

Thank you again in advance for any new reply.

Patrick

Answer (score -1):

Using Jquery you could wrap your link in a span with an ID and then get the value of that ID and push it into another span id.

HTML

```
<span id="span1">
    <a id="idname" class="classname" href="www.MySite.com/image-name.jpg">link-text</a>
</span>
<p>
    <span id="span2"></span>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
var span1val = $('#span1').html();
$('#span2').html(span1val);
```

Example can be found here.

http://jsfiddle.net/3en2Lgmu/5/

Comment: I think he want to use plain Javascript, not Jquery

Comment: I thought I'd offer an alternative as others have done in this post. I'm new to offering solutions.

Comment: This produces invalid markup.  `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your method that works very well. But, unfortunately, I forgot to say something in my initial request:
the original link is in the bottom part of my page.
And, I would like to have the duplicated link in a upper part of my page
So, would you know how to have the duplicated link above the original link ?